Can't export scene in USD
I have a big 2GB scene I need to export from Blender to Unreal Engine and I tried to do it through FBX but got a crash of Unreal in the middle (maybe too heavy on memory usage, I have 32 GB). So, I'm trying to do it with USD but it doesn't present as an export option in my Blender 4.1 for Open SUSE TW Linux. I can't find a proper addon here. I tried to use these but haven't succeed to build them from sources or use a prebuilt one. How can I add USD export to my Linux Blender? Or how could I import the scene to Unreal simpler?

It's there in the Windows version and seems to be built-in rather than supplied as an addon. This is the Manual section about it and the File > Export menu item is "Universal Scene Description (.usd*)".

How to enable the export?

No idea. I don't use Linux and it's there by default under Windows.

What is your installation source? Is it a trusted source? Also, you might be happy to know that 4.2 is released (and the extensions pages you linked are the replacement for addons from 4.2 and up, but that's not solving your issue regardless).

It's a repository package.

So, not from Blender's nor OpenSuse's official channels? The thing is, USD is part of vanilla Blender and shouldn't need any addon, so it isn't normal to not have import/export options. I'm not familiar with OpenSuse in particular. But to me, it sounds like a recipe for trouble if you go out of trusted sources: not only you can get malfunctioning softwares, but you can also get actual malware instead. Blender seems available on software.opensuse.org so I guess you should at least be able to download a legit OpenSuse-trusted Blender from there.

Repository package means it's included in distributive official sources.

Maybe try Blender's snap build then. Or divide your scene in smaller batches and export in FBX.
